# Should I compare $get value to stored relavent db value?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am trying to implement resetting a users password in codeigniter.

I've created a form that the users sends their email and it creates a row in a 'reset' table that stores their token that is created as well as attaches the token the link sent to the email.

The final step is actually resetting the password. I am not understanding how to make the correct comparison when checking the token attached to the email against the one stored in the db associated with that email, or if that is even the right way to go about it.

In the current code I have, I am unable to get it to pass validation and actually reset the password. Here is my code:

This is the model for creating the token and sending the email:

```
public function validate_retrieve($data) {

            $query = $this->db->where($data)->get('users', '1');

            foreach ($query->result() as $user)
            {
                $user->email;
                $user->salt;
                $user->id;

            }

            $token = sha1($user->email.$user->salt).dechex($user->id);
            $reset_token = array(
                'token' => $token,
                'email' => $user->email
            );

            $insert = $this->db->insert('reset', $reset_token, '1');
            return $reset_token;
        }
```

and the controller:

```
public function retrieve()
        // REQUEST PASSWORD RESET
        // LOADED WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED OFF THE PASSWORD PAGE AND SENDS THE EMAIL WITH TOKEN AND INSTRUCTIONS
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');
            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
            $salt = $this->_salt();

            if($submit)
            // IF THE SUBMIT BUTTON IS SET
            {

                // START PROCESS TO CREATE $USER VARIABLE THAT HOLDS WHAT THE USER ENTERED IN THE FORM AND THAT CAN GET CHECKED AGAINST THE DB IN THE MODEL
                $user = $this->um->validate_retrieve(array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));


                // IF THE USER IS CREATED AND CHECKS OUT AND ALL OF THE ERRORS ARE CLEARED ON THE FORM
                if( $user && $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE ) {

                    $domain = "clci.dev/index.php";

                    // CREATE A TOKEN LINK TO SEND TO THE USERS EMAIL THAT EXIST IN THE DB AND WAS ENTERED

                    $token = $user['token'];
                    $link = "http://www.".$domain."/auth/reset/?token=$token";


                        $this->load->library('email');

                        $this->email->from('noreply@cysticlife.org', 'CysticLife');
                        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email')); 

                        $this->email->subject('Reset Password');
                        $this->email->message("Please go to the following web address to reset your password:\n\n$link\n\n-Your friends at CysticLife\n\nPlease remember to add the cysticlife.org domain to your address book to ensure that you receive your CysticLife e-Notifications as requested.");  

                        $this->email->send();
                        redirect('auth/success');
                        exit;

                    }
                    $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE;
                    $data['main_content'] = 'auth/password';
                    $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
                    $data['email_error'] = 'This email is invalid';
                }
            }
```

now here is what I'm having trouble with, the model for resetting:

```
public function verify_token($token)
          {
            $this->db->where('token', $token);
            $query = $this->db->get('reset');

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;

            }
          }

          public function reset_password()
            {
              $salt = $this->_salt();
              $query = $this->db->get('reset', 1);
              $row = $query->row();

              $data = array(
                      'password' => $this->encrypt->sha1($salt . $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password'))),
                      'salt' => $salt
                    );  
              $this->db->where('email', $row->email);
              $this->db->update('users', $data);
            }
```

and the controller:

```
public function reset_password()
            {
             $this->load->library('form_validation');
             $this->load->library('session');
             $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');
             $this->load->library('encrypt');
             $this->load->helper('url');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required'); 
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
             $salt = $this->_salt();
             $submit = $this->input->post('submit');


             if($submit) 
             {
              $validToken = $this->um->verify_token($token); 
              if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && $validToken == TRUE)
              {

              $this->um->reset_password(array('password' => $this->input->post('password', $salt)));


              $data['main_content'] = 'auth/success';
              $this->load->view('includes/templates/home_page_template', $data);

              }
              $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE;
           $data['main_content'] = 'auth/reset';
           $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
             }
            }
```

I seem to be very close but I am definitely stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://yoursitename.com/reset/[hashcode]
```

send the link to the member email, went password have reset by user.

on web site you will retrieve the hashcode to compare with your database

```
public function reset($hashcode)
 {
    if($hashcode!=null)
    {
        // compare with db
        // if success 
        // redirect to create new password page
        // or show create new password form
    }
 }
```